# iterate through an array of hashes in JSON format from API

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, api, hash

I'm trying to iterate through an array of hashes in JSON format I received from an API. when I call .each on the array, it dives one level deep in to the first element instead of showing all of the elements. the first two elements of the array look like this:

```
[
  {
    "asset_id": "USD",
    "name": "US Dollar",
    "type_is_crypto": 0,
    "data_start": "2010-07-17",
    "data_end": "2020-08-22",
    "data_quote_start": "2014-02-24T17:43:05.0000000Z",
    "data_quote_end": "2020-08-22T01:06:58.9597860Z",
    "data_orderbook_start": "2014-02-24T17:43:05.0000000Z",
    "data_orderbook_end": "2020-08-05T14:38:00.7082850Z",
    "data_trade_start": "2010-07-17T23:09:17.0000000Z",
    "data_trade_end": "2020-08-22T01:19:43.1640000Z",
    "data_symbols_count": 26852,
    "volume_1hrs_usd": 2321607499673.51,
    "volume_1day_usd": 40908494876832.76,
    "volume_1mth_usd": 1714490806719560.56,
    "id_icon": "0a4185f2-1a03-4a7c-b866-ba7076d8c73b"
  },
  {
    "asset_id": "BTC",
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "type_is_crypto": 1,
    "data_start": "2010-07-17",
    "data_end": "2020-08-22",
    "data_quote_start": "2014-02-24T17:43:05.0000000Z",
    "data_quote_end": "2020-08-22T01:07:19.9866602Z",
    "data_orderbook_start": "2014-02-24T17:43:05.0000000Z",
    "data_orderbook_end": "2020-08-05T14:38:38.3413202Z",
    "data_trade_start": "2010-07-17T23:09:17.0000000Z",
    "data_trade_end": "2020-08-22T01:19:41.0000000Z",
    "data_symbols_count": 37490,
    "volume_1hrs_usd": 2608619355599.04,
    "volume_1day_usd": 1026744793672216.61,
    "volume_1mth_usd": 1229382556627007157.08,
    "price_usd": 11430.971377648230409771335978,
    "id_icon": "4caf2b16-a017-4e26-a348-2cea69c34cba"
  },
```

my code looks like this:

```
ticker.each do |currencies| 
            currencies.each do |key, value|
                puts "#{key} #{value}"
            end
        end
```

I was hoping to have each element in "currencies" and each of its attributes as key/value pairs to assign variables. But, when I pry in to this block and check what "currencies" returns, it's only the first element, and its 17 hashes, not the other 9000 elements. I hope that's pretty clear, any help is appreciated.

Comment: So ticker is an array of your 9000 currencies? What does your program output? I'm not sure what you mean when you say "currencies" returns. "currencies" is not a function or a method. Maybe you could post some code with more context? And perhaps the output of the pry session would help.

Comment: I have used just assign your hashes to a ticker variable and it is working fine. and ticker.count also showing me 2. which is expected in this case. Can you write it in a log or print it on console. to check whether you are getting all the currencies correctly.

Comment: Please, provide a smaller model of your hash and state clearly what is your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Think you want `currencies.each_pair` instead of `currencies.each`...
The `each` method iterates over the `ticker` array passing each entry to the block in turn. Just because you gave `currencies` a plural name, it doesn't automatically make it an array, it's still a hash containing the 17 attributes of a single currency each time through the loop.

```rb
ticker.each do |currency|
  currency.each_pair { |key, value| puts "#{key}: #{value}" }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try .with_index on ticker

```
  ticker.each_with_index do |currencies, index|
     puts index.to_s + ': {' 
  
    currencies.each do |key, value|
    puts  "#{key}: #{value}" 
    end
    
    puts '}'
  end
```